# Trace my mistake in this Code Snippet in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I just want to use the switch statement instead of the commented lines below.
If the default value is an integer.

So here my code is not working please identify my mistake.

```
ParameterInfo[] pif = m.GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo p in pif) {
    string ParamType = p.ParameterType.ToString();
    string ConvPType = ConvertToShortForm(ParamType);
    if (p.IsOut)
        ConvPType = ConvPType.Replace("ref", "out");
    strMethodName += ConvPType;
    strMethodName += " ";
    strMethodName += p.Name;

    if (p.IsOptional) {
        var optional_value = p.DefaultValue;
        switch (optional_value) {
            case "":
                strMethodName += @"""" + @"""";
                break;
            case null:
                strMethodName = strMethodName + "=" + "null";
                break;
            case "False":
                strMethodName += " = " + p.DefaultValue.ToString().ToLower();
                break;
            default: strMethodName += ", ";
                break;
        }
    //...
    }
//...
}
```

The commented lines:

```
//if (p.DefaultValue != null)
//    strMethodName += " = " + p.DefaultValue.ToString().ToLower();
//if (p.DefaultValue == null)
//    strMethodName = strMethodName + "=" + "null";
//if (strMethodName.EndsWith("= "))
//    strMethodName += @"""" + @"""";
```

Comment: So the commented lines are correct and work and you want to refactor them?

Comment: Where is the error and what is the error?

Comment: Here instead of commented lines i wanna to use the Switch .here p.DefaultValue is a object type .But for using switch i have converted into ToString().But it showing me the error that can't convert into string type

Comment: What is the value in your p.DefaultValue. Check that before you convert to ToString() and if its of object type, then you can use Convert.ToString() right?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `p.DefaultValue.ToString()` in order to use `optional_value` as the expression in switch statement.

MSDN says that expression in switch statement should be of integral type or of `string` type. You passed expression of type `object`. There is your mistake.